# fork() with of else

Tags: c, if-statement, process, fork

I have below query regarding fork() process:
say I have a code:

```
if(fork()||fork())
printf("1");
else if(!fork())
printf("2");
else
printf("3");
```

out of these, which will be printed 1,2 or 3.
I know fork() returns non-zero for parent process and 0 for child process. So when it hits first statement, first fork() call will return say 1 for parent process and 0 for child process. because theres || operator, second fork() will run only when first operand returns 0. so second fork will be called on child and not on parent. Is my understanding correct? if yes, then 1 will be printed by child. Then will it go to else if and else blocks?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

The first process will print 1.

The child of the original process will print 1 from returning true on the second half of the ||.

The child of the fork after the || will fail the else-if due to the `!` and print 3 while its child will print 2 because !0 is true.

Comment: Thanks @xaxxon. If I am understanding correctly,  will 1 be printed by only parent process of first fork() and not child process? if yes, will parent exit and flow continues with child from first fork() evaluating second fork() after ||?

Comment: The child process of the first fork got a false return on the first fork, so it evaluates the bit after the ||, which causes it for fork again.   The original child then receives a non-0 (true) return value, causing the original if statement to return true.

Comment: Thanks again @xaxxon. I got your point. So, after this child of second fork() will continue with else if(! fork()) block.And because child of this new third fork() returns 0, making else if(! operator) block true, will print 2 and original child from second fork will print 3.